# Need to find the angle between two planes

Tags: plane-geometry

[image]

Lets say, the rings A & B are on top of each other, I say there are completely ordered. If they are side by side (Like both rings on a same plane), then I say they aren't ordered at all. If I just calculate the angle between the normals, then In both cases I get zero degrees. I use tcl scripting to code this. I want to distinguish these both cases based on the angle.

One way of doing it is to draw a line joining the centers and find the angle between the line and the plane. But I found that it isn't giving accurate angle for reason I cannot figure it out. Any other approach to find this?

Comment: ${a} \cdot {b} = ||a|| ||b|| cos \theta$ where $a$ and $b$ are the normal vectors of the planes

Comment: As $b$ is parallel to $b'$, yes the angle will be the same.

Comment: @MattiP. But the problem is when those rings are side by side or exactly on top of each other alligned, the angle will be the same. How can I distinguish which is which?

Comment: @AdupaVasista So you mean, you need to distinguish which Ring is which? Well, that would depend on the platform that you're working with. Is this some programming thing, or how? Are you using a computer program to calculate this?

Comment: @MattiP. Not exactly that. But I want to distinguish the rings based on the angle. Lets say, the rings are on top of each other, I say there are completely ordered. If they are side by side (Like both rings on a same plane), then I say they aren't ordered at all. If I just calculate the angle between the normals, then In both cases I get zero degrees.  I use tcl scripting  to code this.

Comment: A vector can be moved parallel to itself arbitrarily. So normal (vector) of  nuts are always parallel. whether sitting side by side or on top of another in parallel motions

Comment: @Narasimham Thanks for the comment. and that's true. what about the second method I mentioned to differentiate.It works well differentiating side by side and on top configurations, But I am confused in between these two extremes.

Comment: Do you know whats a position vector?

Comment: @Narasimham No.